# VB.NET datagrid filtering with integer "like" query

Tags: sql, vb.net, textbox

I have got a database integer column called lotto, and trying to use 3 text boxes to simultaneously filter datagrid but cannot filter using "LIKE" SQL query for integer values. How to replace "LIKE" to make this work fine? Or is there any faster way to use multiple datagrid columns simultaneously?

```
    If TB_regal_3.Text = String.Empty And TB_lotto_3.Text = String.Empty Then
        Me.Mag_pretyBindingSource.Filter = "kod like '%" & TB_kod_3.Text & "%'"
    ElseIf TB_lotto_3.Text = String.Empty Then
        Me.Mag_pretyBindingSource.Filter = "kod like '%" & TB_kod_3.Text & "%' AND regal like '%" & TB_regal_3.Text & "%'"
    ElseIf TB_regal_3.Text = String.Empty Then
        Me.Mag_pretyBindingSource.Filter = "kod like '%" & TB_kod_3.Text & "%' AND lotto like '%" & TB_lotto_3.Text & "%'"
    Else
        Me.Mag_pretyBindingSource.Filter = "kod like '%" & TB_kod_3.Text & "%' AND regal like '%" & TB_regal_3.Text & "%' AND lotto like " & TB_regal_3.Text
```

System.Data.EvaluateException: 'Nie można wykonać operacji 'Like' na System.Int32 i System.String.'

Comment: It would have helped if you indicated your location in your profile. I do not recognize the language so I can't attempt to translate. In general, you can't compare a string to an Integer. They are 2 different animals. Covert your number to a string.

Comment: Are you asking how to set the filter to something that works as the 'Like' function but for integers?  As far as I know 'Like' only works with strings.  It also looks like you are treating you filter condition as a string.  Is that intended?

Comment: i know that like works for strings, thats why i ask -> what i can use to filter integer column in any other way? VB.NET

Answer (score 0):

I already found an answer:

```
(Convert(lotto, 'System.String') like '%" & TB_lotto_3.Text & "%')
```